# react redux get the a property of container

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have multiple 'sections' in the store. 
Each section has an object_id.

This is my sections reducer:

```
export default function () {
  return [
    {
      object_id: 1,
      title: "section_1"
    },
    {
      object_id: 2,
      title: "section_2"
    },
    {
      object_id: 3,
      title: "section_3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I loop through the store sections and add them to the DOM, however when they get added the ownProps of mapStateToProps appears to be an empty object.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Section extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.object_id);
  }

}

function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps) {
  return { 
    object_id: ownProps.object_id,
    sliders: state.sliders
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Section);
```

Ideally, I want to be able to loop through the sliders that are in the store and see if they have a section_id that matches the sections object_id, however I'm stuck at step 1!

Answer (score 2):

In your `mapStateToProps` selector, `ownProps` should have an `object_id` property. Assuming `state.sliders` is an array, you can use `.some` to inspect the array for a slider that has a matching id. `.some` will return true if it's found, false otherwise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

```
return {
  hasMatchingSlider: state.sliders.some(s => s.section_id === ownProps.object_id)
}
```

Comment: Samo, I feel like this is the touch of genius I am after!!, however for some reason the ownProps.object_id are returning undefined.

Comment: I might need to see the component that renders your `Section` component, if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks Samo, I think it was the component that was rendering the sections that was the problem. I believe I also need to pass the data to the section being created.. as seen in the answer above. Do you know if this is the right way to be doing things in redux/react?.. all the best, j

Comment: Yes, passing in some props to the `Section` component is probably what you were missing.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears the problem was - in the container that was adding the sections, I also need to pass the data. So:

```
  listSections(){
    return this.props.sections.map((section) => {
      return (
        <Section />
      );
    });
  }
```

becomes:

```
  listSections(){
    return this.props.sections.map((section) => {
      return (
        <Section my_section_properties={section} />
      );
    });
  }
```

I now have access to the my_section_properties data object within my section container.

To the people that know, does this seem like a best practice way of doing this?